# how to run, once my object is created in spark

Tags: apache-spark

Please help me out i have installed spark and now i am trying to run the code object is defined ,but what next i am confused do help

```
 scala> import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext

scala> import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

 scala> object  mapTest{
 | def main(args: Array[String]) = {
 | val spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("mapExample").master("local").getOrCreate()
 | val data = spark.read.textFile("file///home/parv/Desktop/1").rdd
 | val mapFile = data.map(line => (line,line.length))
 | mapFile.foreach(println)
 | }
 | }
defined object mapTest
```

Comment: `mapTest.main( Array() )`. You don't have to instantiate SparkSession either because I see you are in spark-shell where SparkSession is already available by the name `spark`.

Comment: thanks a lot it helped

Answer (score 0):

Just say

mapTest.main

on scala shell